# Javascript - addEventListener in if

Tags: javascript, html

Why the first one is working (when the player score is equals to winningScore it's game over and you cannot click the buttons any more) and the commented one isn't? It's excercise from The Web Developer Bootcamp Course on Udemy by Colt Steele.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html
     <html
         <head
            <titleScoreKeeper</title
         </head
         <body

            <h1<span id="p1Display"0</span to <span id="p2Display"0</span</h1

            <pPlaying to: 5</p

            <input type="number"
            <button id="p1"Player One</button
            <button id="p2"Player Two</button
            <button id="reset"Reset</button

         <script type="text/javascript" src="ScoreKeeper.js"</script
         </body
      </html>




var p1 = document.querySelector("#p1");
var p2 = document.querySelector("#p2");
var reset = document.querySelector("#reset");
var p1Score = 0;
var p2Score = 0;
var p1Display = document.querySelector("#p1Display");
var p2Display = document.querySelector("#p2Display");
var max = document.querySelector("#max");
var gameOver = false;
var winningScore = 5;


p1.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (!gameOver) {
        p1Score++;
        if (p1Score === winningScore) {
            gameOver = true;
        }
        p1Display.textContent = p1Score;
    }
});

p2.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (!gameOver) {
        p2Score++;
        if (p2Score === winningScore) {
            gameOver = true;
        }
        p2Display.textContent = p2Score;
    }
});

// if (!gameOver) {
//  p1.addEventListener("click", function() {
//          p1Score++;
//          if (p1Score === winningScore) {
//              gameOver = true;
//          }
//          p1Display.textContent = p1Score;
//     });

//     p2.addEventListener("click", function() {
//          p2Score++;
//          if (p2Score === winningScore) {
//              gameOver = true;
//          }
//          p2Display.textContent = p2Score;
//     });
// }
```

Comment: It doesn't work because you have already attached an event handler. To get rid of event handler you can use `removeEventListener`. Checkout this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. Notice, I'm removing event listeners using `removeEventListener`, if you don't do this, handlers will still kick in on a click!

```
if (!gameOver) {
  p1.addEventListener("click", function p1ClickHandler() {
          p1Score++;
          if (p1Score === winningScore) {
              gameOver = true;
              p1.removeEventListener(p1ClickHandler);
          }
          p1Display.textContent = p1Score;
     });

     p2.addEventListener("click", function p2ClickHandler() {
          p2Score++;
          if (p2Score === winningScore) {
              gameOver = true;
              p2.removeEventListener(p2ClickHandler);
          }
          p2Display.textContent = p2Score;
     });
 }
```